# Pythonで競技プログラムをする時、複数行（入力の終了まで）でなおかつ一行にスペース区切りでデータを入力する時はどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3

どうも、競技プログラムで、Python3を使っているkeito940です。
[このサイト](https://qiita.com/lethe2211/items/6cbade2bc547649bc040#%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E8%A1%8C%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AE%E6%95%B4%E6%95%B0%E3%82%92%E5%8F%97%E3%81%91%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9E%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AB1%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E6%95%B4%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B)に方法が書かれていないので質問させていただきます。
C++の場合は、

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

void main() {
    int a,b
    while(a,b != EOF){
    cin >> a >> b >>endl;
    }
cout << a << b << endl;
return 0;
}
```

でしたが、Python3の場合はどうなるのでしょうか？

追記:デバッグなどに対応させたい時は、[この記事](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40908/debugconsolestdin%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ae%e5%8e%9f%e5%9b%a0%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)も合わせてみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 回答

### とりあえずスペース区切り入力文字をデータに変換する処理

```
from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
  a = line.rstrip().split(' ')
  print(a)
```

### 扱いやすいように2次元配列として持つ方法

```
from sys import stdin

l = []
for line in stdin:
  a = line.rstrip().split(' ')
  l.append(a)
print(l)
```

## 参考

[file - What is the perfect counterpart in Python for "while not EOF" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599639/what-is-the-perfect-counterpart-in-python-for-while-not-eof)
 [How can I remove (chomp) a trailing newline in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-trailing-newline-in-python)

Comment: ありがとうございます！！凄く助かりました！！

Answer (score 0):

```
print("a", "b", "c" )
```

> a b c

こういう感じですか？次のように改行をなくすのも出来るそうです。

```
print("a", "b", "c", sep = "")
```

> abc

```
print(
'''
a
b
c
'''
)
```

> a
>    b
>    c

縦はこんな感じですか。print()のみだと。

```
def suiheinumber():
    columns = int(input());
    i = 0;
    for i in range(columns):
        print(i, end = " ") //" "でスペースを作成。
suiheinumber()
```

> 5 // 任意の入力された数
>   0 1 2 3 4 // iの出力結果。

(end = "")抜きだと新しい列に。

> 5
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

あとは複数行をinput()で一列の文字列を" "で区切るという事ですか。参照のページにも書いてあったので、これも違いますか？

```
a = "A B C"
a = a.split(" ")
print(a)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: 違います。僕が知りたいのは、スペースで区切る複数のデータをどうやって入力するかです。でも、質問に答えていただきありがとうございます。