# DebugConsoleStdInエラーの原因がわからない。

Tags: python, python3

先程は情報提供をしていただきありがとうございます。複数行のデータを入力できるようになったのは良かったのですが、Pycharmでデバッグを行おうとすると、以下のログのようなエラーが出ます。

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 61322 --file C:/Users/keito940/PycharmProjects/AOJTest/AOJTest.py
pydev debugger: process 18256 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 173.3727.137)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1683, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1677, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1087, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/keito940/PycharmProjects/AOJTest/AOJTest.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/keito940/PycharmProjects/AOJTest/AOJTest.py", line 19, in main
    for line in stdin:
TypeError: 'DebugConsoleStdIn' object is not iterable
```

以下は上記のエラーが発生したプログラムのソースコードです。

```
def main():
    # プログラムとしては入力したデータを表示するだけのシンプルなもの。
    l = []

    for line in stdin:
        a = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        l.append(a)

    print(l)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

追記:shingo.nakanishiさんが、解決方法を提示してくれたみたいですので、先ほどと同じプログラムをその方法で組んでみました。

```
import argparse

    def main():
        # プログラムとしては入力したデータを表示するだけのシンプルなもの。
        # なお、入力はテキストファイルで行う模様。
        l = []

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("filename", help="The filename to be processed")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        if args.filename:
            with open(args.filename) as f:
                for line in f:
                      a,b = line.rstrip().split(' ')
                      l.append([a,b])

        print(l)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

クラスに依存しない方法を提供してくれてありがとうございます！！

Comment: 参考になりそうなもの https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630403/reading-from-a-file-with-sys-stdin-in-pycharm

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi これを参考にしてみたいと思います！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: 'DebugConsoleStdIn' object is not iterable

既定の stdin はファイルオブジェクトであり、IOBase を継承しているためイテレートが可能になっています。

> IOBase (とそのサブクラス) はイテレータプロトコルをサポートします。 IOBase オブジェクトをイテレートすると、ストリーム内の行が yield されます。
>   https://docs.python.jp/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase

一方、PyDev 経由ですと stdin が置換されファイルオブジェクトではなくなってしまっているので、イテレートができない、という事だと思います。

> ```
> class DebugConsoleStdIn(BaseStdIn):
> ```
>
> [PyDev.Debugger/pydev_console_utils.py at master · fabioz/PyDev.Debugger > DebugConsoleStdIn](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/master/_pydev_bundle/pydev_console_utils.py#L135)

Comment: なるほど、こういうことなんですね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: DebugConsoleStdIn にも `readline()` は実装されていますので、`while True:\n
    line = sys.stdin.readline()\n
    if not line: break;
` と書く事で標準入力から読み取れると思います。また [fileinput](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/fileinput.html) モジュールも内部では `readline()` を使用し標準入力から読み取ります（既定）ので、`for line in fileinput.input():` と書く事もできると思います。参考: https://maku77.github.io/python/read-stdin.html

Comment: 解決方法を提示してくれてありがとうございました。